# How to pass to JS such array of such objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, response

So I need to pass to my script an array of such arrays `[name, width, height]` and be capable to iterate through such array. In what format, how should my server response and how to request(my server can response on any Http and tcp request in any required form.) So I am in search for easiest in implementing on js side. But I can not use any special JS libs like Jquery. (as I said server can form any kind of TCP and HTTP response.)

So how should look my response to pass such array of arrays to JS and how to read it using JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Comment: That's really only for when you're hindered by the same-origin policy.

Comment: Why so? AFAIK, HTTP requests for JS files are a little faster than Ajax requests (don't know why, that's what it says in High Performance JavaScript, by Nicholas C. Zakas), and parse times are better with a `script` tag, than `eval` and probably `JSON.parse` on response body. There are some downsides compared to Ajax, like the ability to set/read headers, or status codes, but maybe he doesn't need this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just return [JSON](http://json.org)